# PhoneGap 1.4.1 WP7 setRequestHeader unsupported?

Tags: json, utf-8, cordova, xmlhttprequest, content-type

I'm trying to POST some JSON data to a WCF service from WP7 app build with PhoneGap (current 1.4.1 version) but as soon as my XMLHttpRequest object calls setRequestHeader it fails...
As soon as I comment out the  it works again. Is there a way to POST with setRequestHeader, since the WCF service  I'm using can't work without the *xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')* line please??
TIA

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-208